# Geoserver (automatic labeling generalization)

Tags: geoserver, labeling, algorithm, generalization, research

I am a Master student looking to do my thesis in cartographic labelling using GeoServer. The thesis topic will be something like "Cartographic Labelling in Real Time Mapping using Web Services.

I am looking for the best way I could write my algorithm, where I can put my generalization in GeoServer.

I'm not professional in this matter and seek suggestions on how to get started. For example, where can write the algorithms in GeoServer, which programing languages could be used.

The concept is that if you have a real time map and as long as using the zoom the represented data should vary according to a standers that i shall control ... those standards should be algorithm that i will design, but from what i get that there is a pre-generalized option within the sld standard inside the geoserver ... now for me i would like to put my own standards and modify the ( pre-generalized )

Does anyone know where I can enter my algorithms?

In summary, I'm looking for suggestions on the best way to write my algorithm (where? how? which programming language?) and make it usable by GeoServer.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user I recommend taking the [Tour] to see that this Q&A site works quite differently to (and I think much better than) discussion forums and other Q&A sites.  At the moment your question is far too broad and we will need you to **edit** it to try and focus it down to a single issue that has emerged from your research so far, and a description of what you have tried and precisely where you are stuck.

Comment: i did modified my question

Comment: It isn't clear what you've already researched / completed. Also, you might want to try to clean up your text, since currently its quite hard to read. I'll try to edit it, but its hard to do when I'm still not sure what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

[GeoServer](http://geoserver.org) (and it's undelying library [GeoTools](http://geotools.org)) are written in Java so that is the language you will need to use.

The labeling engine is part of the GeoTools [renderer module](https://github.com/geotools/geotools/tree/master/modules/library/render/src/main/java/org/geotools/renderer/label) so you'll need to study and understand how this code works.

Assuming that you would like to eventually add this code to the GeoTools library then you'll need to read the [Developer's guide](http://docs.geotools.org/latest/developer/), which includes information on getting started and how to discuss changes with the existing developers.